# React - Why is the value not being passed to the other component?

Tags: reactjs

this simple react app WILL EVENTUALLY be a calculator, but for now I am trying to make the screen display the value of the button clicked.  Why is the "display" element not showing the value of the button clicked when a button is clicked?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: ' '
        }
    }

    handleCallback = (str) =>{
        this.setState({data: str})
    }

    render(){
        const {data} = this.state;
        return(
            <div class="App">
                <h1>String Builder</h1>
                <div class="display">{data}</div>
                <Button value="1"/>
                <Button value="2"/>
                <Button value="3"/>
                <Button value="4"/>
                <Button value="5"/>
                <Button value="6"/>
                <Button value="7"/>
                <Button value="8"/>
                <Button value="9"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Button extends React.Component{
  
    onTrigger = (event) => {
        this.props.str = this.props.value;
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <input type = "button" onClick={this.onTrigger} value = {this.props.value}/>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: well, the `Button` component doesn't have a link back to the parent component (`handleCallback` isn't passed as props, nor is it called from the `onTrigger` eventhandler inside your `Button` component)

Comment: There's currently no reason for it to--you don't pass the callback, `Button` doesn't call the non-existent callback property with its assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
class Button extends React.Component{
  
    onTrigger = (event) => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <input type="button" onClick={this.onTrigger} value={this.props.value}/>
        )
    }
}
```

And then call the component like this:

```
<Button value="1" onClick={this.handleCallback}/>
```